# Android - OnItemClickListener dont't capture event click in adapterview

Tags: android, checkbox, imageview, onitemclicklistener

I have an activity that has a AdapterView to display a gridview of ImageView

The Activity:

```
package com.xlck.mislistas

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.xlck.mislistas.adapters.ExpandableHeightGridView;
import com.xlck.mislistas.adapters.ImageGridAdapter;
import com.xlck.mislistas.adapters.ImageGridAdapter.ViewHolder;
import com.xlck.mislistas.adapters.ImageGridBean;

public class AmigosActivity extends SherlockActivity {
...

    private ExpandableHeightGridView gridViewImagenes;
        gridViewImagenes = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.grvImagenes);

    // Adapter GridView
    gridViewImagenes.setAdapter(imageGridAdapter);
    gridViewImagenes.setExpanded(true);
    .
    .
    .

    // Listener
    gridViewImagenes.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Do something ...;
        }
    });
}
```

The Adapter:

```
package com.xlck.mislistas.adapters;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.xlck.mislistas.R;

public class ImageGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;

private List<ImageGridBean> items;

// Constructor
public ImageGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageGridBean> items) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    ImageGridBean item = (ImageGridBean) items.get(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_imagen, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.uid);
        holder.txtNombre = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        holder.imagen = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgImagen);

        holder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkItem);
        holder.txtFondoNombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFondoNombre);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtId.setText(item.getId());
    holder.txtNombre.setText(item.getNombre());
    holder.imagen.setImageBitmap(item.getImagen());
    if (item.getId().equals("0"))
        holder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public ImageGridBean getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


// --------------------------------------------------------< ViewHolder >---
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

/* private view holder class */
public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtId;
    public TextView txtNombre;
    public TextView txtFondoNombre;
    public ImageView imagen;
    public CheckBox check;
}
}
```

I have this Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" >

        <TextView
            .../>

        <ImageView
            .../>

        <TextView
            .../>

        <TextView
            ... />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Well, if i click in ImageView, it fire the event click and the listener capture it, but if i click in CheckBox the event click don't fire.

What I doing wrong? What I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually CheckBoxes have their own click handlers to toggle the checkmark, so the gesture is consumed by the CheckBox and it never reaches your AdapterView.

Comment: Hi Sam,

I thank you for your response.

As I understand, we can not access the CheckBox Adapter Class from Class Activity, correct? Would you capture it in the adapter and maybe then notify the Activity Class?

Sorry, I'm new to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to put the adapter into the Activity class. In Class Adapter put a listener both ImageView and CheckBox component, since these listener invoking a method of the Activity class.

Thanks to all for your time and response!!!

Comment: Since your question was answered, could you accept the correct answer? Just check the checkbox near the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:focusable="false"`

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  Add the above code to the CheckBox in your layout file.

Answer (score 0):

@Sam is right, checkboxes handle clicks on their own and the click event never reaches the AdapterView.

Now, technically speaking, you could set `android:clickable="false"` for your checkbox in the layout file, and then the click event would get delivered up the view hierarchy, but in this case you won't be able to do anything useful with the checkbox, it will just always stay unchecked.

Here's what would be a better approach. Move the "do something" into a different method and add another onClickListener for the checkbox, to do the same thing:

```
gridViewImagenes.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        doSomething();
    }
});

myCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        doSomething();
    }
});

}

private void doSomething() {
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you will have to implement a `OnCheckedChangelistener` to the `checkbox`, in your case to `chkItem`.

See [**CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)

The implementation would be something like...

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkItem);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {   
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {
            // checkbox is checked - doSomething()
        } else {
            // checkbox is unchecked
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi neo108,

I thank you for your response.

As I understand, we can not access the CheckBox Adapter Class from Class Activity, correct?

Class and adapter are in different packages. Maybe I should put the adapter in the Class Activity?

Comment: @neo108 The problem with setOnCheckedChangeListener is that it will trigger every time the checkbox is updated, even if it's done from the code. I.e. your program is updating the values from the shared preferences, it sets the checkbox state - boom! onCheckedChanged() fires.

Comment: Hi @AntonCherkashyn, you are right, the `SetOnCheckChangeListener` is fired every time the checkbox is changed/updated.